# React adding array elements to dropdown?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui

Given an array `const places = [" a1", "a2", "a3"];` and

```
  <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
    <InputLabel id="dropdown_label">Testing</InputLabel>
    <Select
      value={5}
      onChange={handleChange}
      label="Testing"
    >
      <MenuItem value={10}> {places[0]} </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={20}>{places[1]}</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={30}>{places[2]}</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
```

How can I make it so menuItem is created for each value in places when places is of varied size?

Comment: You can use `Array.map` to render all the list items. Check [Lists and keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to `map` over the `places` array and return the `MenuItem` component. See the example below. I've modified your code to make it work. Don't forget to add the `key` property to the component returned from `map`.

```
<FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
  <InputLabel id="dropdown_label">Testing</InputLabel>
  <Select
    value={5}
    onChange={handleChange}
    label="Testing"
  >
  {places.map((place, i) => (
    <MenuItem key={i} value={(i + 1) * 10}>{place}</MenuItem>
  )}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```